# BI framework using angular

Tags: angular, user-interface, data-visualization, user-experience, graph-visualization

I wanted to develop a BI framework that take json values as data and convert them into visuals like bar graphs and pie chart.
    Here is the list of thing that i wish to implement in it .
    1 - The framework should have the option to let user select the type of visuals they want to use to display the metrics from json data .
    2 - The visuals should have some kind of drag and drop option . 
    3 - The visuals should be adjustable in terms of size and color using point and click .
    3 - It should have a drill down option . 
    in other terms some thing that does similar to what tablue would do .
    Any suggestion/advice as to where i can start and what can i use to build this.I would prefer to develop this in Angular but i am open to all technologies .

Comment: Hey, start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Jota . Maybe i should have asked this question on quora .The idea is very vague right now so i am not sure how to tag it .Having read this question here ,is there anything that come's to your mind that can direct me the direction of light .